# how to load components one after another without replacing the previous component in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I am new to angular 5 and I am trying to route multiple components inside the single div tag , below is my code:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'course',
    component: POC1Component
  },
  {
    path: 'playlist',
    component: POC2Component
  }  
];
```

In the above code I have two different components

```
    <div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and this is my router outlet code, whenever I am clicking on the below link tags
it is replacing the components .

```
<a routerLink="course"></a>
<a routerLink="playlist"></a>
```

I simply don't want to replace the existing with the next click component.
I want to append the next clicked component after the previous components.

Comment: Then you're not using the good tool. You should have a single component and a single route, and that component should use an ngIf to remove or add the second one to its template. Or, if you want two routes, then the second one should be a child of the first one, and the first component should have a router-outlet in its template.

Comment: route replaces the app content, the way you can handle is the conditional rendering on the basis of your requirement.

Comment: can you please share me some example so that I may understand properly.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf, https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple router-outlet conditionally with named outlets like : -
//The main/first page

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

//add some ngIF condition on click

```
router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
```

define router like :

```
{
  path: 'abc',
  component: abcComponent,
  outlet: 'popup'
}
```